Understanding rust lifetime
Even though I felt like I understand rust lifetime clearly, I found a gap in my knowledge.
To summarize, why this code is invalid
struct Token<'a> {
    slice: &'a str,
}

struct WrappedToken<'a>(&'a Token<'a>);

trait ToWrappedToken<'a> {
    fn to(&'a self) -> WrappedToken<'a>;
}

impl<'a> ToWrappedToken<'a> for Token<'a> {
    fn to(&'a self) -> WrappedToken<'a> {
        WrappedToken(self)
    }
}

fn to_wrap<'a>(token: Token<'a>) -> Box<dyn ToWrappedToken<'a> + 'a> {
    Box::new(token)
}

fn main() {
    let token = Token {
        slice: "It's working well.",
    };
    let r = to_wrap(token);
    r.to();
}

It errors:
error[E0597]: `*r` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
25 |     let r = to_wrap(token);
   |         - binding `r` declared here
26 |     r.to();
   |     ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
27 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `*r` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `r` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Box<dyn ToWrappedToken<'_>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.

But that isn't the case. This code should be vaild to my knowledge. If it is invalid then why this code is valid. I just replaced Box with a reference. Nothing more.
struct Token<'a> {
    slice: &'a str,
}

struct WrappedToken<'a>(&'a Token<'a>);

trait ToWrappedToken<'a> {
    fn to(&'a self) -> WrappedToken<'a>;
}

impl<'a> ToWrappedToken<'a> for Token<'a> {
    fn to(&'a self) -> WrappedToken<'a> {
        WrappedToken(self)
    }
}

fn to_wrap<'a>(token: &'a Token<'a>) -> &'a dyn ToWrappedToken<'a> {
    token
}

fn main() {
    let token = Token {
        slice: "It's working well.",
    };

    let r = to_wrap(&token);

    r.to();
}

Both of them should be valid in here.

I think the main issue is that the full type of token in your first example is Token<'static> and r doesn't live that long.

The short answer is that Token<'static> is assigned to token. While token's own lifetime is within main(). However your to() method assumes &'static Token<'static> (in this case) which is not true. (I don't have any more time, so I can't write a full answer.)

If you read the compiler error carefully, you'll see it doesn't like that it blames the end of main function, saying that *r dropped here while still borrowed. borrow might be used here, when r is dropped and runs the destructor for type Box<dyn ToWrappedToken<'_>>
